# Django query multiple summed values

Tags: django

I have two tables:

Ticket Table

```
id  paid_with_tax  location
1   5              A
2   6              B
3   7              B
```

TicketAdjustment Table

```
id  ticket_id  value_with_tax
1   1          2
2   1          1
3   1          2
4   1          3
5   2          5
```

The query I use:

```
Ticket.objects.all().annotate(
   paid_amount=Sum(
        F('paid_with_tax') +
        Coalesce(F('ticketadjustment__value_with_tax'), 0)
    )
).values(
    'paid_amount', 'location'
).annotate(
    Count('id)
)
```

the query would return the following:

```
[
 {
    id__count: 6,
    paid_amount__sum: 28,
    location: A
 },
 {
    id__count: 2,
    paid_amount__sum: 18,
    location: B
 },
]
```

but the above is incorrect since the Ticket Table id=1 values are duplicated by the TicketAdjustment Table values.

how can i get the query to sum the TicketAdjustment Table values before adding them up.

Some constraints:
- the order of the calls would ideally stay the same, as I have a function which returns the queryset to be filtered thurther

The final result should look as followins:

```
[
 {
    id__count: 1,
    paid_amount__sum: 13,
    location: A
 },
 {
    id__count: 2,
    paid_amount__sum: 18,
    location: B
 },
]
```

models.py:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    paid_with_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)


class TicketAdjustment(models.Model):
    value_with_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)
```

Comment: Can you show your `models.py` for these two models, please?

Comment: added the models.py view

Answer (score -1):

As I understand this aggregation can not be done even using raw sql query. Because the result of joining Ticket with TicketAdjustment will be like:

[image]

So, we can't just sum all `value_with_tax` related to some ticket with `paid_with_tax` and group that by location.

I couldn't find solution to perform this in one sql query. But I have found how to perform this in two queries:

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.values(
    'location',
).annotate(
    count=Count('id', distinct=True),
    paid_amount=Sum('paid_with_tax')
)
# <QuerySet [
#     {'paid_amount': 5, 'count': 1, 'location': 'A'},
#     {'paid_amount': 13, 'count': 2, 'location': 'B'}
# ]>

adjustments = TicketAdjustment.objects.annotate(
    location=F('ticket__location'))
.values(
    'location',
).annotate(
    paid_amount=Sum('value_with_tax')
)
# <QuerySet [
#     {'paid_amount': 5, 'location': 'B'},
#     {'paid_amount': 8, 'location': 'A'}
# ]>

def find_paid_amount_for_list_and_location(l, location):
    for item in l:
        if item['location'] == location:
            return item['paid_amount'] or 0

for obj in tickets:
    paid = find_paid_amount_for_list_and_location(adjustments, obj['location'])
    obj['paid_amount'] += paid

tickets
# [
#     {'location': 'A', 'paid_amount': 13, 'count': 1},
#     {'location': 'B', 'paid_amount': 18, 'count': 2}
# ]
```

But this is not super efficient solution, and I think that you should create new table for locations and just have FK to that table? In this case you will able to perform these calculations in one query on db side.

Comment: @bum-bam-bum So, I think it is really impossible to do that query with current table structure. Have you thought about implementing location as separate table?